# Ruby hit a key x number of times

Tags: ruby, macos

I want to write a Ruby program to hit the 'a' key 100 or infinite times.  any help or tips to write a program like this?  I could use an example or help?

I just want to hit a key repeatedly a number of times.

Comment: Do you mean on a web page? In an application? If the latter, you'll have to let us know what your OS is.

Comment: in a application or for an example an autoclicker in OSX

Comment: It is impossible to hit a key infinite many times. And what do you mean by a program to hit a key? Is that program supposed to be connected to an actuator that presses a key?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby can't dispatch system events itself. For OS X you could use the [AXElements](https://github.com/AXElements/AXElements) gem:

```
require 'AXElements'

100.times do
  type 'a'
  sleep 1
end
```

The above is equivalent to hitting <kbd>a</kbd> 100 times (waiting a second between each hit).