# How do I a trigger keyboard event in ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, keyboard

I want to trigger certain key-presses like <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> and arrow keys. I've googled and am surprised to not be able to find the solution.

**EDIT**

More specifically, I want to trigger some global keyboard shortcuts through ruby script.

Comment: Key events in a terminal, a browser, a desktop window?

Comment: Could you define "global"? :-)

Comment: Global OS level shortcuts. OSX.

Comment: There's a gem called AXElements, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25382115/477037

Comment: Thanks Stefan, trying it out. Running into some errors but fighting them. Also trying the answer below by p11y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, you can use AppleScript to do that. Here's an example that performs the keyboard shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

```
tell application "System Events" 
  keystroke "w" using {control down, option down, command down}
end tell
```

For the arrow keys, use `key code` instead of `keystroke`:

```
# Key codes for arrow keys:
# 
# LEFT  123
# RIGHT 124
# UP    126
# DOWN  125

tell application "System Events" 
  key code 123 using {control down, option down, command down}
end tell
```

You can invoke AppleScript from Ruby by shelling out to `osascript`:

```
def osascript(script)
  system 'osascript', *script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten
end

osascript <<-END
  tell application "System Events" 
    keystroke "w" using {control down, option down, command down}
  end tell
END
```

Sources

- [Using Applescript to Execute a Complicated Keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236741/using-applescript-to-execute-a-complicated-keystroke)
- https://gist.github.com/dinge/6983008

Comment: The [applescript keycodes](http://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/) can be found at the link provided :)